# preg_match() error trying to match variable

Tags: preg-match, php

I keep getting an error when using this and I am not sure why. Any help would be amazing. I have Googled it and found examples but I get the error even with other peoples examples.

```
$statement = $list[$i];
echo $statement;
preg_match("/$statement/i", $q)
```

I also tried this and neither work:

```
$statement = '/' . $list[$i] . '/i';
echo $statement;
preg_match($statement, $q)
```

The error I get is:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

When I echo out the `$statement` I get: `"/Who/i"` (without the quotes)

Comment: Well, tell us the content of `$statement`, but chances are, you are looking for `preg_quote`.

Comment: @Wrikken I have edited the post so you see what is the $statement is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that whatever's in `$statement` will actually produce a VALID regex, e.g.

```
$statement = '(a|'; // note lack of closing )
preg_match("/$statement/", $text);
```

will actually produce the regex

```
/(a|/
```

which is invalid, because there's no closing `)` to finish off the capture group. You can get around this with:

```
$statement = preg_quote('(a|');
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

which will escape any regex metacharacters so you produce a valid regex in the end.

Essentially, you're probably suffering from the regex equivalent of an SQL injection attack.